# HTA and Find Function Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hta

```
Sub search       
Set objExl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWb = objExl.Workbooks
objWb.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls")
Set strbol = objWb("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls").Sheets(1).Cells.Find(document.getElementById("q").Value, Range("A1"), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)
Set objDiv = document.getElementById("content")
objDiv.innerText = "Result: " & objWb.Sheets(1).Cells(strbol.Row,strbol.Column).Offset(0,-4).Value      
objWb("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls").Close
Set objWb = Nothing
Set objExl  = Nothing
End Sub
```

Above is HTA code which gets query word from HTA textbox, finds that word in excel, and returns/displays resulting offset row value in content named div. 
I can run script successfully till opening of excel file.
But script gives error at line : Set strbol . . .
Error message : Subscript out of range.

I tested find method in excel vba it worked their, but not in HTA
note: posting from IE6, so pardon for indents and formatting error.

Comment: Try this `1` Change `Set objWb = objExl.Workbooks` to `Set objWb = objExl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls")` Then `2` Delete the line `objWb.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls")` and then `3` change `Set strbol = objWb("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls").Sheets(1)....` to `Set strbol = objWb.Sheets(1)...`

Comment: Also change `objWb("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls").Close` to `objWb.Close`

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Made changes, makes code look small and better. But now error is on same line but for Range("A1") value (look after parameter) Error message : Type Mismatch 'Range'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fully qualify that range.

I have also replaced `xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext` with their values. I am not sure that in `hta`, like in VBS you could define a constant at the top of the code

Try this (**UNTESTED as I have never worked in hta**).

```
Sub search()
    Set objExl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWb = objExl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\book.xls")
    Set strbol = objWb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(document.getElementById("q").Value, objWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), -4163, 2, 1, 1, False, False)
    Set objDiv = document.getElementById("content")
    objDiv.innerText = "Result: " & objWb.Sheets(1).Cells(strbol.Row, strbol.Column).Offset(0, -4).Value
    objWb.Close
    Set objWb = Nothing
    Set objExl = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EXTRA NOTES**:

Since you are using `.Find`, you need to also trap the code to see if you actually found a match else `objDiv.innerText = "Result: " & objWb.Sheets(1).Cells(strbol.Row, strbol.Column).Offset(0, -4).Value` will fail.

Something like

```
If Not strbol Is Nothing Then
    objDiv.innerText = "Result: " & _
                       objWb.Sheets(1).Cells(strbol.Row, strbol.Column).Offset(0, -4).Value
End If
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments Below)**

Code tested in VBS. I create a file `C:\Sample.xlsx` and typed "Sid" in Cell `N95` and then ran the VBS File which has the below code. It worked with no error and showed me a message box `$N$95`

```
Dim objExl, objWb, strbol

Set objExl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWb = objExl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xls")
Set strbol = objWb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find("Sid", objWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), _
             -4163, 2, 1, 1, False, False)

msgbox strbol.address

objWb.Close
Set objWb = Nothing
Set objExl = Nothing
```

Comment: Set strbol = objWb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(document.getElementById("q").Value,, -4163, 2, 1, 1, False, False) > Made code to work. > But couldn't understand, what if some one wants to find from a defined range for eg after B5. > Any way, Siddharth Rout, I would like to use this opportunity, to thank you for teaching me how to use Win API (windows/child windows controlling functions) via your blog. I follow you on Microsoft's Forum too (technet and msdn).

Comment: In such a case you have to specify like I did above `objWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")` For `B5` it becomes `objWb.Sheets(1).Range("B5")` And also ... Thank you :)

Comment: Yes! I got the theory, but when I put to practise, even Range("A1") refuses to work. So I had to drop it, since excel by default, does that, and my current requirement does not need B5. I hope, I shouldn't have future situation where I have to search from B5, and I don't have an answer for doing that. Same works properly in VBA, but not in vbscript of HTA.

Comment: I tested the above code in VB Script and it works just fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: Perfect I got the reason, I need to mention compelete range name not just partial address. Instead of using just Range("A1"), I should have used objWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") in Find Method.
I was getting Error message : Type Mismatch 'Range'. But now all is well. Thanks for showing demo code.